# Subprocess.call() won't run kill all, I'm on macOS using python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to kill an app using `killall` on macos, but everytime I try to do it, it doesn't kill the app. I have the right name and all but it still won't kill the app.

My code:

```
def KillApp(appName):
    
    """

    This will close a program if the app is open.

    """
    os_name = system()
    
    if os_name == "Darwin":
        
        os_name = "macOS"
    
    if system() == "Windows":
        
        return call(["taskkill", "/f", "/im", appName], shell=True)
    
    elif system() == "Linux":
        
        return call(["killall", appName], shell=True)
    
    elif system() == "macOS":
        
        return call(["killall", appName], shell=True)`
```

It returns None and doesn't kill the program.

Comment: When `shell=True` you need to pass the command as string: `return call(f"killall {appname}", shell=True)`

Comment: @MauriceMeyer Please add an answer in order to help others searching for a similar solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`subprocess.call()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) uses the same function signature as the [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) constructor.
The command executed via `Popen` needs to be passed in different ways depending on shell argument:

- `shell=True`,  the command needs to be a **`string`**.
- `shell=False`,the command needs to be a **`list`**.

Examples:

```
return call(["killall", "-9", appName], shell=False)
return call(f"killall -9 {appName}", shell=True)
```